# If cancel the twitter bootstrap navbar collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I work on a php website and use bootstrap library. I'll cancel collapse function from the navbar. I solved the responsive problem as follows;

> **hidden-(?)** and **visible-(?)**

**Simple:**

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker visible-sm-block visible-xs-block"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Contact</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

### Screens

**Medium, large and more screens:**

[image]

**Small Devices (Pad):**

[image]

**x-Small Devices (Phone) Screen 1:**

[image]

**x-Small Devices (Phone) Screen 2:**

[image]

**x-Small Devices (Phone) Screen 3:**
" My support minimum width for devices: 230px "

[image]

**x-Small Devices (Phone) Screen 4:**
" More small devices see corrupt navbar "

[image]

Does this method lead to a possible mistake? And do you think that 230px is enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are trying to ask 2 questions here :

1) Should I even support for any device below 230px minimum width ?

2) If yes, then how do I target styles for this range and below. ?

Ans. 1)

The device which comes below say 320px comes under `wearables` devices and yes you can support for these devices if you wish ofcourse.

Ans. 2)

You can target this range by using media queries and `max-width : 230px`, like so

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 230px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Check my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g40vahnn/1/). Demonstrates a simple example on how the style changes once the width goes below 230px.